# Can I run dot NET core on ARM/raspberry pi?

Tags: .net-core

I can debug and build on my main machine which is x64 but I'd like to execute the code on my pi. After googling there was [a comment](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/140#issuecomment-228419531) that said

> you will need to build and publish your code on another machine and then copy it to the Pi.

However he seemed to be unsure and it appears I should execute by using `dotnet` which appears not to be arm so it appears theres no way to run the app

How do I run my app on dot net core on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 4):

Not yet, there are no official sdk builds for ARM. Seems that they are close, but I haven't heard for any schedules. This is the thread I check from time to time to track their progress.
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/3977

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Now with .net core 2.0 and the corresponding sdk you can publish your application for arm architectures: `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm`. Copy the resulting binaries to you RPi and enjoy.

Be aware of some pre-requisites for linux such as the following packages: curl, libunwind and gettext.

You can check this post for more info: [Toggle Raspberry Pi GPIO pins with ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/09/01/toggle-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-with-asp-net-core-20/)