# How to publish from windows VS2017 .NET Core application for linux-arm?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, archlinux-arm

How to publish from windows VS2017 .NET Core application for linux-arm?
When I try to make new publish profile I can choose as Target Runtime:
portable, win-x86, win-x64, osx-x64 and linux-x64.
(menu: Build->Publish->New profile->Folder->Advanced->Target Runtime)

How to add posibilities for publish to linux-arm and linux-x86?
Should I install something more to my developer machine?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and .NET Core SDK do you have installed? Also there is no `linux-x86` runtime target AFAIK

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017 ver. 15.7.3  
and 

.NET Core SDK ver. 2.1.0

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40695645/982149 mind answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013842/982149

Answer (score 0):

Go in your terminal and in your directory of your project and run

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm
```

Then you get the binaries and can copy them to your Raspberry Pi.

No need to install additional things, just the `dotnet` SDK what you already done if you can build that for your own machine.